# How do you mine Obsidian without burning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you mine obsidian in a cave without it falling into lava?

Comment: @gnovice It's a close call, but I think this question is distinct enough. It's more about safety precautions against falling into obsidian, and specifically about found obsidian, rather than farmed obsidian.

Comment: @Zibbobz: I disagree. I think the 6 answers on the other question cover pretty much all you need to know.

Comment: You need a diamond pickaxe to mine obsidian - that's a pretty easy thing to find out on the wiki, so I removed it from your question.

Answer (score 5):

First thing's first, you need a Diamond Pickaxe to mine obsidian.  There is no way around this.

As for staying safe, there's one thing you can do to help yourself out tremendously.

Pour water over it.

By bringing a bucket of water with you on your obsidian mining expedition, and pouring it over the obsidian you want, you can ensure that any lava flows that open up while mining will immediately become either cobblestone or more Obsidian when the water touches it.

To get the maximum efficiency out of this though, you should only ever mine said obsidian when it is at foot-level with you (one block high from the level you are standing on), and never mine it from above or below, where it could reveal a lava flow or, worse yet, cause you to fall into lava.

The water nearby will also handily give you a way to be extinguished very quickly.

You should also be holding shift when mining, just in case you DO open up a hole into lava.  Holding it and not lettign go until you're absolutely sure you will never fall into lava.

Or you could [build a farm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10465/whats-the-safest-way-to-farm-obsidian-without-burning-to-death)